# Issue with calculating sum when matching text criteria in filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am facing an issue here to calculate sum while matching a text in Power BI, below is the query I wrote.
My table has data like Month and value associated with it, I want to dynamically calculate the sum as dates changes. I want to extract the Month from the date and match it with the lookup table and calculate the sum.

I am unsure what should I do here, when I use the below formula I'm getting blank values. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Current Month Quota =

VAR current_month = FORMAT(TODAY(), "MMMM") 
//--I even used convert function to convert it to string.

Return
CALCULATE(
    SUMX('RSD Quota', 'RSD Quota'[Target Value]), 
    'RSD Quota'[Month] = current_month
)
```

[image: Here is the dataset snapshot]

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don’t know if weekday function does any other than getting the day of the week, am i missing anything else ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! If your "current_month" variable is working correctly, then I suspect that some other filters may be filtering out the data in the 'RSD Quota' table. Can you verify that you don't have any filters affecting RSD Quota?

Comment: Its in a blank sheet, no filtering is being done on it. Thanks for quick response tho!

Comment: Does RSD Quota have a relationship with some other table? At this point, it’s hard to say why you are getting blank values. If you can share a sample file, that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code-

```
Current Month Quota =

VAR current_month = FORMAT(TODAY(), "MMMM") 

Return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('RSD Quota'[Target Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('RSD Quota'),
        'RSD Quota'[Month] = current_month
    )    
)
```